# wsimport exception "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/api/ErrorListener"

Tags: wsimport

wsimport has been deprecated, so I downloaded [JAX-WS RI 2.3.1](https://javaee.github.io/metro-jax-ws/) that has wsimport. My PC is running:

```
java version "21.0.2" 2024-01-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21.0.2+13-LTS-58)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.2+13-LTS-58, mixed mode, sharing)
```

When I run `wsimport -keep -verbose https://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceio.wsdl`, I got the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/api/ErrorListener
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3549)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3754)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2442)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:150)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.api.ErrorListener
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
        ... 24 more
```

I get the same when I use a local wsdl file. I suspect this error has nothing to do with the WSDL file. Is it possible that the JDK 21 is not compatible with JAX-WS RI 2.3.1 which was built 5 or 6 years ago?

Is there a new version of wsimport?